# Customizing Django Admin to call stored procedures

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I am developing an application for upload and process some files.
I get the suggestion of only use the admin interface.

The application will call some stored procedures to get the files from an ftp server. The stored procedure to retrieve the files works fine.

I can call stored procedures from DJANGO creating a model with a cursor to execute the procedure and pass the parameters from a view.

model:

```
class PRCEDURE_FTP():
      def ftpload(self,pv_fecha):
          cursor = connection.cursor()
          query = "begin django_sp.procedure_test(:foo); end; "
          param = {"foo":pv_fecha}
          sp =  cursor.execute(query,param)
          cursor.close()
          return sp
```

I pass the parameters from a template rendered with this view:

```
def TestView(request):
    form = TestForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
          carga = PROCEDURE_FTP()
          sp = carga.ftpload(request.POST['fecha'])
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return render(request,'test.html',{'form':form})
```

and works fine without any issue

But I don't know how to do it from the admin interface.
I wanna know if this is possible from the admin interface and how can add custom template or how can call the model to execute the stored procedure

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Django `ModelAdmin` allows you to [define custom view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) in it.  So move your view code to the `ModelAdmin` and override the `get_urls()` method:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^test_view/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.test_view))
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def test_view(self, request):
        form = TestForm(request.POST or None)
        ...
```

To use the admin layout in your `test.html` template extend it from `admin/base_site.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block title %}My test upload{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks @catavaran. I only have one more question. To create a custom form is the same concept like the views

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `test_view()` is a regular view and you can use the same form as in your non-admin view.

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking in other thing. My problem now is when I try to execute the procedure from the custom template I get the error: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED.

Comment: I create another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464530/django-admin-custom-template-page-not-found-error). I test the view and the form and works fine outside the admin. but when I try to run from the admin I get the error Method not allowed.

Comment: In this another thread the error is `Template not found` and not `Method not allowed`.  You still getting the error 405?

Comment: If modified the url file I can access the template and get the error method not allowed. If try to use get_url I can't access to the template