# django admin custom template page not found error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I am trying to modify the django admin interface and I cannot see the custom templates.

In the admin.py file I added this model admin

```
class FTPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

      def get_urls(self):
          urls = super(FTPAdmin,self).get_urls()
          my_urls = patterns('',
                    (r'^ftp/$',self.admin_site.admin_view(self.FTPView)))
          return my_urls + urls


      def FTPView(self, request):
          form = FTPForm()
          if request.method == 'POST':
             if form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
          return render_to_response(request,'ftpform.html',{'form':form})
```

In my project folder I have a template folder with an admin subfolder with the custom template
(/DjangoProjects/projectftp/templates/admin/ftp.html)

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block title %}My test upload{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

In my settings.py file I change the template dir:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR + '/templates/',
)
```

In my forms.py I create a simple form:

```
class ProcFTPForm(forms.Form):
      anio = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
      mes = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(ProcFTPForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.helper = FormHelper()
```

I try to see the template in the url "ip:port/admin/ftp" or ip:port/admin/app_name/ftp or ip:port/ftp.

Any suggestion

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

this is the code of my model:

```
class Lectura_FTP():
      def leer_ftp(self):
          cursor = connection.cursor()
          sp = cursor.callproc("CARGA_LISTA_ARCHIVOS_PC")
          cursor.close()
          return sp
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `render` shortcut instead of the `render_to_response`:

```
return render(request, 'ftpform.html', {'form': form})
```

Or change the `render_for_response` call to this:

```
return render_for_responce('ftpform.html', {'form': form},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**UPDATE**: And url of the view is `ip:port/admin/app_name/model_name/ftp/`

Comment: I try the two methods an I get the same error page not found. which will be the url I have to put in the browser ip:port/admin/ftp or what. By the way I am using an admin interface called django-suit

Comment: The correct url is `ip:port/admin/app_name/model_name/ftp/`

Comment: I try 'ip:port/admin/pc/lectura_ftp/ftp' and I get the same error. I add the code of  my model

Comment: Because the class to execute the procedure doesn't inherit from the models.Model I canregister the model. How can I access to the class or can create the same class in the admin file??

Comment: You have two options: 1. Customize the admin site:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class or 2. Create a regular view protected by `@user_passes_test` decorator and assign it to the `/admin/ftp/` in the `urls.py`.